# Loop through modal togglers in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a bunch of buttons and modals, each button opens a modal with something inside it, I'm using vue-clickaway to close the modal when clicking outside of the modal but I don't want to make an open and close method for each of the togglers. How can I loop through this?

Basically I want a single open and close method that works for all the modals.

Modals:

```
data(){
 return {
  toggleModal1: false,
  toggleModal2: false,
  toggleModal3: false,
  toggleModal4: false,
  toggleModal5: false,
  toggleModal6: false,
  toggleModal7: false,
  toggleModal8: false
}},
```

My open/close toggle methods:

```
methods: {
show: function(){
  this.toggleModal1 = true;
},
close: function(){
  this.toggleModal1 = false;
}},
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

call the function with the number of modal as `show(1)`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    show: function(num) {
      let modal = "toggleModal" + num;
      this[modal] = true;
      console.log(modal + " show clicked");
    },
    close: function(num) {
      let modal = "toggleModal" + num;
      this[modal] = false;
      console.log(modal + " close clicked");
    }
  },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="el in [1,2,3,4,5]">
<button @click="show(el)" >Show{{el}}</button>
<button @click="close(el)">Close{{el}}</button><br>
</template>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried this already it says "func is defined but never used" even though I do use it on my tags @click="show(1)"

Comment: which function?

Comment: I create a running snippet. it may help you .